# AngularJS remove item from scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My template:

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in article.comments">
    {{ comment.date }} by {{ comment.author }} <button type="button" ng-click="removeComment($index)">remove</button>
</div>
```

My JSON comments:

```
"comments": [
    {
        "author": "Syl A",
        "date": "2014-07-02",
        "content": "lol"
    },
    {
        "author": "Syl B",
        "date": "2014-07-02",
        "content": "lol"
    },
    {
        "author": "Syl C",
        "date": "2014-07-02",
        "content": "lol"
    }
]
```

My controller:

```
$scope.removeComment = function (key) {
    // This is what I want to remove
    // Object {author: "Syl A", date: "2014-07-02", content: "lol", $$hashKey: "004"}
    console.log($scope.article.comments[key]);
};
```

The following snippets is not OK, it does nothing;

```
$scope.article.comments.splice[key, 1];
```

The following snippets are not OK, the object is removed but in the view got "by remove", the complete line is not removed and I can't remove more than one item `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]`:

```
$scope.article.comments[key] = undefined;
delete $scope.article.comments[key];
```

The following snippet is not OK, the object is removed but in the view got "by remove", the complete line is not removed:

```
$scope.article.comments[key] = {};
```

So I didn't find a solution on SO to make an "all-in-one" remove, DOM and "data". Why my `splice` doesn't work here?

Comment: Why do you have `$scope.article.comments.splice[key, 1];` and not `$scope.article.comments.splice(key, 1);`

Comment: My totally bad, it works now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using splice wrong is the problem.

Update your splice to use ( ) instead of [ ]

`$scope.article.comments.splice(key, 1);`